# Using hexcode in ti basic program on ti 84+

Tags: assembly, ti-basic, z80

Recently I have been reading about different hex codes that do cool stuff like Archiving something inside a program among other things. The way I try to incorporate these into my (ti 84+)basic coding is by using a separate program and "calling it"(   ASM(prgrmNAME)    ) in the original program. The issue is that sometimes I want to go back to the original program, but I can't use return because once I use AMSprgrm I can't do basic coding in it.

Is there some way that I can incorporate hexcodes in middle of my programs, or some other solution to get around this?

Comment: You should probably specify the exact model you're working with.

Comment: @Michael ok- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the non-color model, you can use a program like TPROG to copy an archived program to a temp program and just run that copy. TPROG is available in the ticalc file archives and I believe the hex opcode is available either within that download or in the "Zeda's Hex Codes" resource also available there.

Comment: I just downloaded ur hexcodes yesterday I just couldn't figure out how to implement them. Can u please elaborate/explain the copy an archived program to a temp prog part for me? I'm new to this assembly and hex code stuff - I only understand stuff that I can do from the calculator itself.

Comment: How would I put this tprog into practice?

Comment: @JediPythonClone: For a visual explanation, I made this gif for another website: http://tibasicdev.wdfiles.com/local--files/hexcodes/asmprgm-example.gif

Press the [prgm] button and select new (use arrows then enter). Press [2nd][0] to open the catalog and scroll down to the "AsmPrgm" token. Type in the hex code. You can have line-breaks (by pressing enter) as you type, but only when multiples of two digits are formed. Now you can compress if you want, otherwise, you can run TPROG. I'd download that for the readme, though it is straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

Using a command in the Doors CS libraries can do this easily as long as you have Doors CS installed. The run hexcode command is

```
det(20, "HEXCODE
```

where the hexcode you want to execute is in the quotes. You can add closing quotes and parentheses, but it is not necessary. Doors also automatically appends a C9, but you can enter it manually as well without harm. So,

```
det(20, "EF7045
```

would turn off the run indicator when the program is run using Doors.